# Converting an image (3D array) into a 2D matrix in a specific order

Tags: matlab

Say you have an image with 200 pixels. It will be a 10 x 20 x 3 array where the pages are layer of colors (Red, green and blue). How do I convert that, into a 3 (row) x N (columns eg. 2000) so that each row represents the color (row 1 is red, row 2 is green etc.) and the columns represent pixels

I've tried reshaping but I get a 3 by N matrix that fills the rows downwards and not horizontally (so each row is a mixture of colors and not a specific color).

Answer (score 2):

Your idea using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) is correct, but as you found out yourself, the order of the array dimensions is important. Luckily, you can manipulate this using [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html). So, in your case, the "color information", i.e. the third dimension,  should be set to the first dimension, so that `reshape` works as intended.

Let's have look at this code snippet:

```matlab
% Set up dimensions
rows = 10;
cols = 20;

% Generate artificial image
img = uint8(255 * rand(rows, cols, 3));

% Get color independently for each channel
r = reshape(img(:, :, 1), 1, rows * cols);
g = reshape(img(:, :, 2), 1, rows * cols);
b = reshape(img(:, :, 3), 1, rows * cols);

% Reshape image with previous dimension permuting
img2 = reshape(permute(img, [3 1 2]), 3, rows * cols);

% Compare results
rOK = (sum(r == img2(1, :)) == rows * cols)
gOK = (sum(g == img2(2, :)) == rows * cols)
bOK = (sum(b == img2(3, :)) == rows * cols)
```

For a simple comparison, I fetched the "color information" separately, cf. the vectors `r`, `g`, and `b`. Then I permuted the original `img` as described above, reshaped it to a `3 x N` matrix as desired, and compared each row with `r`, `g`, and `b`.

Hope that helps!